# Why, in linear programming, do we impose explicitly the $\mathbf x\ge\mathbf 0$ constraints?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming

[Linear programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming) tasks are generally presented as optimisation problems of the form
$$\max_{\bf x} \mathbf c^T\mathbf x \quad \text{such that} \quad \mathbf x\ge\mathbf 0, \,\, A\mathbf x\le \mathbf b.$$
These have a clear geometric interpretation, as maximising the cost function over a polyhedral set, and I can understand the need to impose $\mathbf x\ge0$ to try to ensure a bounded feasible region. But then again, this cannot be the only reason, as the feasible region can still be unbounded unless $A,\mathbf b$ are suitably chosen.

However, what I'm not clear about is why use specifically $\mathbf x\ge\mathbf 0$ to "bound" the feasible region. Wouldn't it be more general to consider problems with constraints of the form $A\mathbf x\le\mathbf b$ and $B\mathbf x\ge \mathbf d$ for some $B,\mathbf d$ instead? Of course, depending on the choice of $B,\mathbf d$, one can or cannot have non-empty or bounded feasible regions, but the same applies for the formulation with $\mathbf x\ge\mathbf 0$.

Is there any particular reason, other than simplicity, to formulate linear programming problems using specifically the constraint $\mathbf x\ge0$? Is it just because many problems people are actually interested in use that constraint, or are there specific issues in developing the theory in the more general case?

Answer (score 1):

There are various Core reasons, which put together, give us the Primary reason why it is stated like this currently.

(1) The Vector $X$ contains the Design or Decision Variables, which are **generally** like this:

- (A) how much money to invest in US Market versus how much money to invest in AUS market ( with 0 being minimum )
- (B) how much water to buy versus how much water to extract from Well ( with 0 being minimum )
- (C) how many toy tanks to manufacture versus how many toy rockets to manufacture ( with 0 being minimum )
- (D) how much farm land to lease versus how much farm land to buy ( with 0 being minimum )

There is no Negative Utilization or Negative Production ! Thus $X \ge 0$ is natural.

(2) If we use $CX \ge D$ **instead of** $X \ge 0$ , we have to move away from the origin, making the complicated situation even more complicated, even without starting the analysis ! With Current formulation, we know that Origin is within our View.

(3) If we use $CX \ge D$ **along with** $X \ge 0$ , we can easily convert that to $-Cx \le -D$ and include these new conditions with $AX \le B$ !

(4) With all these consideration, the "Standard" is to use $X \ge 0$ making it easy to compare various algorithms and enabling Discussion with Peers ! This is known as the "Canonical" Form.

Comment: you're absolutely right about the third point, I should have caught that. With that in mind, the question becomes for me: *why not just define linear programming only via the constraint $Ax\le b$ for some $A,b$?* Your other arguments are essentially about the most common applications and hardness of the theory, which are fine, but still make me wonder whether the theory changes in any significant way if we just ask about, say, $\max_x c^T x$ such that $Ax\le b$

Comment: well, sure, but the same is true with the condition $x\ge0$, if $A$ and $b$ are not appropriately chosen. Unbounded feasible regions are very much considered when the theory is developed.

Comment: The non-negativity restriction is added only for those variables which are meaningful ; Otherwise there is no restriction on those variables ; A variable which has restriction $x \le 0$ is converted to a new variable $y \ge 0$ where $y=-x$ and this is listed in the vector $X \ge 0$ ; Hence there is a "Natural Separation" of Constraints into two vectors $AX \le B$ & $X \ge 0$.

Comment: ok, but why impose the restriction at all. I can appreciate that it is natural in many situations, but what I'm trying to get at here is, what if I'm dealing with a linear optimisation problem where the constraint $x\ge0$ doesn't naturally appear, and is replaced by some other linear constraint? How much of the theory, if any, will need to be changed to accommodate for this more general case?

Comment: You seem to be hung up on *a* form in some text. This is not set in stone. Here for instance, you can find a table with three common standard forms https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_linear_program. Solvers typically work with $Ax\leq b$, and then simple bound constraints $l \leq x \leq u$ can be communicated too.